# System API Error Handing in Linux, WIndows and Android

Tags: c++

I am developing a cross platform platform that is suppose to run on the following platform

1. Windows x64
2. Linux x64
3. Windows ARM
4. Linux ARM
5. Android ARM

The program is used in interfacing with multiple Serial Ports (up to 20) and server connectivity using MQTT or ReST-JSON.

I am extensively suing asynchronous operation and threading in my application

I have couple question regarding error handling

1. Can I handle WIN API error in libc `errno` integer variable or do I have to use `GetLastError` in windows and `errno` in Linux + Android.
2. Is `GetLastError()` thread safe?
3. Is `strerror_s` thread safe?
4. Will `strerror_s` be available in Linux and Android if I select C11 or greater during program build?

My current implementation

```
//Returns the last error, in string format. Returns an empty string if there is no error.
std::string GetLastErrorAsString(void)
{
#ifdef _WIN64
    //Get the error message ID, if any.
    DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();
    if (errorMessageID == 0) 
    {
        return std::string(); //No error message has been recorded
    }

    LPSTR message_buffer = nullptr;

    //Ask Win64 to give us the string version of that message ID.
    //The parameters we pass in, tell Win64 to create the buffer that holds the message for us (because we don't yet know how long the message string will be).
    size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, errorMessageID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&message_buffer, 0, NULL);

    //Copy the error message into a std::string.
    std::string error_message(message_buffer, size);

    //Free the Win64's string's buffer.
    LocalFree(message_buffer);

    return error_message;
#elif __linux__ || __ANDROID__
    if (errno == 0)
    {
        return std::string(); //No error message has been recorded
    }
    size_t error_message_length = strerrorlen_s(errno) + 1;
    std::array<char, error_message_length> error_message;
    //char errmsg[errmsglen];
    strerror_s(error_message.data(), error_message_length, errno);
    return std::string(error_message.data());
#endif
}
```

Comment: You can't use any WIN API functions in Linux (exception, you *can* use [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) as a library to get a Windows(ish) environment).

Answer (score 0):

> Can I handle WIN API error in libc errno integer variable or do I have to use GetLastError in windows and errno in Linux + Android.

No, if you are calling Win APIs you will need to use `GetLastError()` to get the last error.

> Is `GetLastError()` thread safe?

Yes. ["Retrieves the calling thread's last-error code value. The last-error code is maintained on a per-thread basis."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror). Always search MSDN for information about Win API.

> Is `strerror_s` thread safe?

In general, I don't know. A quick search found that it may be on Windows:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/issues/2281

> Will strerror_s be available in Linux and Android if I select C11 or greater during program build?

[Yes.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror)

Always search cppreference.com for C and C++ library reference information. It clearly indicates the answer with the "since C11" in the header.

Comment: `strerror_s` will be used in Linux and Android. I couldn't find any information on thread safety for `strerror_s` on Linux and Android platform. In fact, I couldn't find any reference to it in Linux man pages. Is their a way I can test the tread safety for the function before deployment.